# VB.NET one click or key event for multiple datagridviews

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, keyevent, mouseclick-event

I have 4 datagridviews, let's say Dgv1, Dgv2, Dgv3, Dgv4

Suppose I want to move up and down the rows with the up and down arrow key.

Is there a way to code this one time for all datagridviews?

At the moment I have to code it 4 times like this:

```
Private Sub Dgv1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Dgv1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up OR e.KeyCode = Keys.Down OR e.KeyCode = Keys.PageUp Or e.KeyCode = Keys.PageDown Then
        Dim crRowIndex As Integer = Dgv1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        Value = Dgv1.Rows(crRowIndex).Cells(4).Value.ToString
        ' Do more stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

And this four times. All datagridviews get different data from different sql tables but the functionality is the same. Although I need a different cell in other datagridviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to this:

```
Private Sub Dgv1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Dgv1.KeyUp, dgv2.keyup, dgv3.keyup, dgv4.keyup
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up OR e.KeyCode = Keys.Down OR e.KeyCode = Keys.PageUp Or e.KeyCode = Keys.PageDown Then
    Dim dgv as DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim crRowIndex As Integer = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Value = dgv.Rows(crRowIndex).Cells(4).Value.ToString
    ' Do more stuff
End If
End Sub
```

Basically you are just adding to the Handles list and then using sender to get the specific datagridview that is being handled

Comment: This will not compile with `Option Strict On` because `sender` is of type `Object` which does not have a property named `CurrentCell`.  You need to cast `sender` to the correct type using:  `DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)`